# What test I can use if I have nonnormally distributed multiple response variables and one categorical predictor?

Tags: multiple-regression

I am trying to analyze the effect of a single categorical (4 factors) independent variable on 4 different response variables which are not normally distributed. Kindly suggest to me what test should I use in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple regression would be a good place to start (separate regressions for each response variable). With a single covariate you can do the simplest anova.

It is a misconception that you need normally distributed response variable for regression/anova. For the inference to be valid you only need the residuals to be normally distributed. But if you are not interested in inference (eg you only care about prediction) you don't even need that.

Comment: Thank you so much.  This suggestion will certainly help.